# Checking jquery object content

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Does anyone know, why jquery behaves like this:

```
var $test = $(window).add(document).add("body");
$test.is(window) -> false
$test.is(document) -> true
$test.is("body") -> true
```

How do I find out whether a jquery-object contains the window via "is"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $test = $(window).add(document).add("body");
$test.is(function(index, elements) {
    return this === window;
});
```

the jQuery "is()" method checks the nodeType of the elements being passed. Document has a nodeType of 9. Body has a nodeType of 1. Window has no nodeType, ergo "undefined" which evaluates to false. To get around this, build your own filtering function as illustrated above.

Comment: Yeah...document and body both have the NodePrototype in their prototype chain and are "HTML-Nodes", window is completely different and extends the WindowProtptype. Thanks for the hint. Would be nice for jquery to include that.